# #define include alternative for hardware cursor?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

This program I'm working on has a 3D (hardware/non-hardware) cursor option that I'm trying to make a config option for.  Right now it's set using a preprocessor #define macro that sets the types of CursorType, CursorName, and CursorDisplay.  Currently, the only way that I can toggle on or off the 3D cursor is to comment or uncomment the #define USE_3D_CURSOR line (which is very bad).

```
#define USE_3D_CURSOR
#if defined (USE_3D_CURSOR)
  #include <osgDB/ReadFile>
  #define CursorType osg::Image *
  #define CursorName const stringobj& 
  #define CursorDisplay osg::Texture *
#elif defined (_MSC_VER)
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <osgViewer/api/Win32/GraphicsWindowWin32>
  #define SLASH "\\"
  #define CursorType HCURSOR
  #define CursorName LPTSTR
  #define CursorDisplay HMODULE
#elif defined(__linux__)
  //...
```

So as I said before, I'd like to change this to be a config file option that can be set before runtime.  But, I'm not sure what is the best way to go about doing this.  Should I use templated functions maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible by definition, since `#define` and `#include` statements always will be evaluated during compile time.

You'll need a kind of OS abstraction layer for this, instead of the `#define CursorType` etc.

In other words: Define abstract interfaces to describe cursor specific behaviors, and have OS specific implementations for these. Use a factory pattern to instantiate the correct implementations at compile time, use the interface to configure specific behavior and capabilities and properties at runtime.

I'd recommend reading about the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) and [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) patterns. IMHO the whole thing is a bit too complex to provide you with a code sample here (may be I'm just too lazy now). If s.o. else gets what I mean, and is willing to give one, or has a good source to such abstraction layer, feel free!

Comment: That sounds great. I'll check into the patterns you mentioned.